Problem with Chrome 130 / Undetected Chromedriver / Python / Selenium
I crossposted this to the UC github discussions:
I'm a hack hobbyist so please forgive my lack of codiing skills.
Yesterday my chromedriver and uc (I think) updated and I'm now getting a Timeout exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\PycharmProjects\webscrape\nba.py", line 157, in <module>
    mgm_data = mgm_scrape(Url, max_list_len)
  File "C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\PycharmProjects\webscrape\CommonFuns.py", line 407, in mgm_scrape
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "participant")))
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

When I use the normal chromedriver (not uc) everything runs without error.
OS - Win11
selenium - 4.16.0
seleniumbase - 4.22.1
Python - 3.9
URL - https://sports.ks.betmgm.com/en/sports/basketball-7/betting/usa-9
Code that works - first 4 lines are the only difference:
**service = Service()
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)  # mgm only works with normal chrome webdriver**

   # driver = sbDriver(uc_cdp=True, incognito=True)
   

   # driver.set_window_size(930, 930)
   # driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
   # time.sleep(20)
   # driver.save_screenshot('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/nowsecure.png')
   mgm_web = Url
   driver.get(mgm_web)
   sleep_time = 2.5 + (max_list_len / 40)
   time.sleep(sleep_time)

   # time.sleep(4) # ncaabb tourney sleep time to click button

   # try to click more button twice for long list lengths
   button_loops = int(max_list_len / 50)
   if max_list_len > 73:
       for i in range(button_loops):
           try:
               more_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                 '#main-view > ms-widget-layout > ms-widget-slot > ms-composable-widget > ms-widget-slot > ms-tabbed-grid-widget > div > div')
               more_button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
           except NoSuchElementException:
               print("no mgm button")
               break
           else:
               time.sleep(2)
               more_button.click()
               time.sleep(3)


   # manage stale element errors
   timeout = sleep_time
   for i in range(4):
       try:
           WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "participant")))
           mgm_team_name = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "participant")
           # WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
           # '//*[@id="main-view"]/ms-fixture-list/div/div/div/div/ms-grid/div/ms-event-group[1]/ms-six-pack-event[1]/div[2]/a/ms-event-detail/ms-event-name/ms-inline-tooltip/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div')))
           # mgm_team_name = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
           # '//*[@id="main-view"]/ms-fixture-list/div/div/div/div/ms-grid/div/ms-event-group[1]/ms-six-pack-event[1]/div[2]/a/ms-event-detail/ms-event-name/ms-inline-tooltip/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div')
           for j in range(len(mgm_team_name)):
               mgm_team_name[j] = mgm_team_name[j].text
           print(mgm_team_name)
           print('mgm name stale element loops', i)
           break
       except StaleElementReferenceException or NoSuchElementException or TimeoutException:
           continue

Code that used to work but now doesn't:
driver = sbDriver(uc_cdp=True, incognito=True)


    # driver.set_window_size(930, 930)
    # driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
    ...  same code as before


It did resolve when Chrome 131 was released.
